# How to get only number of rows/columns with values in them in a QTableWidget?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtablewidget

I have a tablewidget on PyQt5 with a default number of 20 columns. Only the first two columns have any values in them, the rest are empty. Is there any way to return the number of columns/rows with values in them.

This    `new_cols = self.tableWidget.columnCount()` was the only thing I could find on returning column count.

Answer (score 0):

There's no direct way to do so, and there's no "shortcut" (unless you're absolutely certain that if a certain row/column combination is empty, the following rows and columns are empty too).

The following assumes that you intend an "empty" item as an item that has no value set (including items that have been modified and then "cleared").

```
    def dataExtent(self):
        maxRow = maxCol = -1
        for row in range(self.tableWidget.rowCount()):
            for col in range(self.tableWidget.columnCount()):
                item = self.tableWidget.item(row, col)
                if not item or not item.text():
                    continue
                maxRow = row
                maxCol = max(maxCol, col)
        print('Max row: {}\nMax column: {}'.format(
            maxRow + 1, maxCol + 1))
```